# Clear selection of Listbox control items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a listbox which contains a user control

```
    <Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=_myControl}" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <local:SearchUsercontrol />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The user control contains

```
             <DataGrid
                 x:Name="dataGrid"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window,AncestorLevel=1}}"
                 IsReadOnly="True"
                 GridLinesVisibility="None"
                 local:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding ColumnCollection}"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False"

                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=recordsBusinessObject}"

                CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}"

                ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource HeaderSTyle}">
            </DataGrid>
```

When I select a row in datagrid  I want the other row selection to clear in other listbox items.

In my Listbox changed event i tried this

```
   void myListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        myListBox.UnselectAll();
    }
```

Thanks All

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your setup. Can you post code and XAML and an example of what you want to happen in detail?

Comment: did you try: myListBox.SelectedItem=null;?

Comment: If the list box items do not actually have to be selectable (and looking at your item template it would seem that they don't) then just replace the `ListBox` control with an `ItemsControl` instead. I can post an answer with more detail if it's not clear how you would go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

myListBox.UnselectAll(); Unselects all ListBoxItems in myListBox and does not unselect DataGridRows within each ListBoxItem.

This is a solution which works for a situation where you got two viewModels:

1. MasterVm (contains a collection of Items of type ItemVm)
2. ItemVm (contains a bindable boolean named IsSelected)

This is the modified code of simple version of your xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" 
            SelectionChanged="myListBox_SelectionChanged"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MasterItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <!-- here we bind to IsSelected of ItemVm -->
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                        <!-- datagrid row is Selected => select listBoxItem -->
                        <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="DataGrid_Selected"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And the code behind:

```
//This event handler makes sure when a ListBoxItem is unselected
// it automatically unselects all inner items
private void myListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RemovedItems != null)
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
            foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
            {
                if (item is MasterVm)
                    //implement this method
                    (item as MasterVm).UnselectAll();
            }
}

//This event handler makes sure that when datagrid row is Selected
// it automatically selects listBoxItem
private void DataGrid_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dg = sender as DataGridRow;
    var lbi = FindAncestor<ListBoxItem>(dg);
    lbi.IsSelected = true;
}
```

You'll need a helper like this:

```
public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
    if (parent == null) return null;
    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindAncestor<T>(parent);
}
```